# Possible causes of failed garbage collections

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Here is some simple test code I wrote:

```
class Simple
{

}

class Finalizing
{
    public static volatile bool AllowFinalization = false;
    ~Finalizing()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Finalizer starting.");
        while (!AllowFinalization) ;
        Debug.WriteLine("Finalizer finishing.");
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static string CheckAlive(WeakReference wr)
    {
        if (!wr.IsAlive)
            return "dead";

        try
        {
            return "alive in gen" + GC.GetGeneration(wr);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return "dead";
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        var simple = new WeakReference(new Simple());
        var finalizingShort = new WeakReference(new Finalizing());
        var finalizingLong = new WeakReference(new Finalizing(), true);
        var suppressedShort = new WeakReference(new Finalizing());
        GC.SuppressFinalize(suppressedShort.Target);
        var suppressedLong = new WeakReference(new Finalizing(), true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(suppressedLong.Target);

        Debug.WriteLine("Simple " + CheckAlive(simple));
        Debug.WriteLine("FinalizingShort" + CheckAlive(finalizingShort));
        Debug.WriteLine("FinalizingLong " + CheckAlive(finalizingLong));
        Debug.WriteLine("SuppressedShort " + CheckAlive(finalizingShort));
        Debug.WriteLine("SuppressedLong " + CheckAlive(finalizingLong));

        Debug.WriteLine("");
        Debug.WriteLine("Collecting...");
        GC.Collect();
        Debug.WriteLine("Simple " + CheckAlive(simple));
        Debug.WriteLine("FinalizingShort " + CheckAlive(finalizingShort));
        Debug.WriteLine("FinalizingLong " + CheckAlive(finalizingLong));
        Debug.WriteLine("SuppressedShort " + CheckAlive(finalizingShort));
        Debug.WriteLine("SuppressedLong " + CheckAlive(finalizingLong));

        Debug.WriteLine("");
        Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for finalizers...");
        Finalizing.AllowFinalization = true;
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Debug.WriteLine("Simple " + CheckAlive(simple));
        Debug.WriteLine("FinalizingShort " + CheckAlive(finalizingShort));
        Debug.WriteLine("FinalizingLong " + CheckAlive(finalizingLong));
        Debug.WriteLine("SuppressedShort " + CheckAlive(finalizingShort));
        Debug.WriteLine("SuppressedLong " + CheckAlive(finalizingLong));

        Debug.WriteLine("");
        Debug.WriteLine("Recollecting...");
        GC.Collect();
        Debug.WriteLine("Simple " + CheckAlive(simple));
        Debug.WriteLine("FinalizingShort " + CheckAlive(finalizingShort));
        Debug.WriteLine("FinalizingLong " + CheckAlive(finalizingLong));
        Debug.WriteLine("SuppressedShort " + CheckAlive(finalizingShort));
        Debug.WriteLine("SuppressedLong " + CheckAlive(finalizingLong));
    }
}
```

Basically, it makes some different types of weak references to different types of objects and inspects what is happening those objects are after certain garbage collection events. The output is expected, like this:

```
Simple alive in gen0
FinalizingShortalive in gen0
FinalizingLong alive in gen0
SuppressedShort alive in gen0
SuppressedLong alive in gen0

Collecting...
Simple dead
FinalizingShort dead
FinalizingLong alive in gen1
Finalizer starting.
SuppressedShort dead
SuppressedLong alive in gen1

Waiting for finalizers...
Finalizer finishing.
Finalizer starting.
Finalizer finishing.
Simple dead
FinalizingShort dead
FinalizingLong alive in gen1
SuppressedShort dead
SuppressedLong alive in gen1

Recollecting...
Simple dead
FinalizingShort dead
FinalizingLong dead
SuppressedShort dead
SuppressedLong dead
```

It's interesting to see that all objects with finalizers, even suppressed ones, survive a collection. But that's not what this question is about.

I copy-pasted that same code to the beginning of my windows forms project's main method, before anything else in the program happens. I expected the same results, of course, but here is the output I am getting:

```
Simple alive in gen0
FinalizingShortalive in gen0
FinalizingLong alive in gen0
SuppressedShort alive in gen0
SuppressedLong alive in gen0

Collecting...
Simple alive in gen1
FinalizingShort alive in gen1
FinalizingLong alive in gen1
SuppressedShort alive in gen1
SuppressedLong alive in gen1

Waiting for finalizers...
Simple alive in gen1
FinalizingShort alive in gen1
FinalizingLong alive in gen1
SuppressedShort alive in gen1
SuppressedLong alive in gen1

Recollecting...
Simple alive in gen2
FinalizingShort alive in gen2
FinalizingLong alive in gen2
SuppressedShort alive in gen2
SuppressedLong alive in gen2
```

In other words, objects simply don't get collected, even though I'm explicitly running GC.Collect(). Does anyone have any tips on how to debug this? What could possibly be causing it? Keep in mind this is code that references some other assemblies so is it possible that they could be messing with my garbage collection somehow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @bit What were some of the guidelines I broke, if I may ask? It's a concrete issue with research done before posting.

Comment: You run this in debug mode, right? Try in release mode (you have to write your output to a file then.

Comment: I tried the release build, replacing Debug with Trace. It actually works as expected then.

Comment: It also seems like normal object collection still works consistently in the debug build. I allocated a couple gigabytes worth of small temporary objects and the memory footprint of the application didn't move at all. The weakly referenced objects still remained in Gen2, though. The only conclusion I can make is that the WeakReference doesn't work consistently, possibly only for Debug builds.